# Json_array ploblem, Mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

everyone!
I'm trying to write a query that uses the function "json_array".
e. g.: 
`select json_array(column1,column2) from tb1`.
And thats work right.
But how can i use this functions without writing a columns name.
e. g.: 
`select json_array(*) from tb1`.
Is it possible to write like this?

Comment: Directly not possible. You will need to use Information_schema to get the name of columns in a specific table; then prepare a dynamic sql query and execute it.